# How to add a nuget package to the package.config the proper way?

Tags: c#, command-line, nuget, nuget-package, xamarin-studio

For my C# project I am maintaining a `packages.config` which includes all the dependencies my project requires. Over the time I have been copy-pasting the entries manually using a regular text editor, checking in the version number I found on the NuGet website and so on. To restore the package upon a checkout, I use `nuget -o nuget-packages install packages.config` which worked good so far (I am using Xamarin Studio on non-windows systems, so no VS available).

I was just realizing that messing with the `packages.config` in a text editor couldn't be the intended way. I know from npm and bower that a `npm install --save-dev <pkg-xy>` will to the job and write the package version back to the config. Is there an equivalent of this in NuGet.exe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line this not supported. You will have to edit the packages.config file manually, or write a utility to do this work for you, or extend NuGet.exe with this feature.

There is no equivalent in NuGet to NPM's **npm install -save**

Currently the only way to have the packages.config file automatically updated when you want to install a new NuGet package to your project is to use an IDE, such as Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio, and actually install the package. Using NuGet.exe from the command line does not have an option to add/remove entries in to/from the packages.config file when installing a new package.

NuGet.exe does have an **update** command which will update the package to the latest version. Whilst this would update your packages.config file it also updates your project file by adding any assembly references that the NuGet package needs.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be editing *packages.config*. Package Restore doesn't do what you think it does. It simply downloads any missing packages that are listed in *packages.config*.

You might think this is what you want, but Package Restore does **NOT** add references to your project. It also doesn't do any of the other things the package creator had intended like running an *install.ps1* script.

When installing a package, NuGet handles all of this, so your project files have added references, content, etc. This and the *packages.config* file is what you would commit to source control. You can leave out the actual *packages* folder, so you don't have to commit large binary files.

When you open the solution and build, NuGet will see that the packages are missing and will download them as if you had checked them in. The actual "install" was already done (and committed). That is all that Package Restore does: no more, no less.

If you are using Xamarin Studio, you can install NuGet by following the instructions here:

https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin

Comment: I'm sorry but you completely missed my question. I am aware of everything you are saying. I want to know what is the proper way to ADD a package to packages.config. As in "I decide my project needs a new library, lets add it from nuget". I know that it won't be added as project reference.

Comment: Hmm.. well that's what I'm trying to tell you. The *proper* way to add a package to *packages.config* is to use NuGet to install it. NuGet will then update the file. Sure, there is nothing preventing you from manually updating the file, but that is not the *proper* way.

Comment: @Kiliman Nuget install does not seem in any way to affect the `packages.config` file. I run `nuget install xunit.runner.console  -SolutionDirectory .` and it ends with `Successfully installed 'xunit.runner.console 2.1.0' to ./packages`. But `git diff` shows nothing. Only thing that happened is that the package was downloaded. So it seems that @matt-ward might be right in saying that a IDE is the only way.

Comment: Yes. `nuget install` is not the same thing as `Install-Package` from Package Manager Console. It's too bad they named it that, since it would be more accurate to call it `nuget download`.

Comment: It's too bad nuget exists at all, having previously worked with npm I'm continuously comparing them. But I was wondering at the difference between using `nuget ...` and the Package manager console. thanks